# Removes token beginning with specific characters

Tags: python, string, tokenize

Hi I am trying to remove all those token which are contained within the my predefined list (prefixes). Below is my code and is not removing the tokens.

```
prefixes = ('#', '@')
tokens = [u'order', u'online', u'today', u'ebay', u'store', u'#hamandcheesecroissant', u'#whoopwhoop', u'\u2026']

for token in tokens:
    if token.startswith(prefixes):
       tokens.remove(token)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really work to remove items from a list whilst iterating over it.

You can use a list comprehension

```
tokens = [token for token in tokens if not token.startswith(prefixes)]
```

Or create another list, and then append the items you want to keep to that list instead:

```
new_tokens = []

for token in tokens:
    if not token.startswith(prefixes):
       new_tokens.append(token)
```

Comment: You can just add this to your previous answer instead of creating two answers.

Comment: Hi @Harald I tried the above appending to list algo but it's giving error AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'.